# Invalid characters in the path in VB.NET and MySQL query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Good evening, I have problems inserting data into a table when this data contains the letter "ñ", my code is this:

I have the database in MySQL and the collation of the tables is UTF8_general_ci

```
Private Sub Regisrar_ingreso()
        Dim iReturn As Boolean
        Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection("Data Source=x.x.x.x; initial catalog=carmelin_Asistencia; user id=carmelin_ricardo;password=xxxx.;")
                Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
                With sqlCommand
                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO ASISTENCIA (`NOMBRE`, `APELLIDOS`, `GRADO`, `SECCION`, `HORAINGRESO`, `HORASALIDA`, `FECHA`, `MES`, `AÑO`, `DNI`, `CELULAR`, `REPORTADO`) values (@NOMBRE,@APELLIDOS,@GRADO,@SECCION,@HORAINGRESO,@HORASALIDA,@FECHA,@MES,@AÑO,@DNIs,@TELEFONO,@REPORTADO)"
                    .Connection = SQLConnection
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMBRE", DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(2).Value.ToString)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@APELLIDOS", DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(3).Value.ToString)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@GRADO", DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(4).Value.ToString)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SECCION", DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(5).Value.ToString)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@HORAINGRESO", Date.Now.ToShortTimeString)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@HORASALIDA", " ")
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHA", Date.Now.ToShortDateString)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@MES", Date.Now.Month.ToString)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@AÑO", Date.Now.Year.ToString)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DNIs", DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(1).Value.ToString)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@TELEFONO", DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(6).Value.ToString)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@REPORTADO", "PENDIENTE")

                End With
                Try
                        SQLConnection.Open()
                        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        iReturn = True
                    Catch ex As MySqlException
                    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
                    iReturn = False
                    Finally
                        SQLConnection.Close()
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using



        DataGridView2.Update()
    End Sub
```

When I try to insert the data that contains a Ñ not tilde I get the following error:

"Invalid characters in the path" and in the database insert the information like this: "NU? EZ"

Help me please.

Comment: Show us the connection parameters, especially the charset.  Show us the table definition.

Comment: The connection parameters are there, the table is configured in UTF8_general_ci

Comment: @RicardoRafaelRivas Just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Ok, I understand, I would also like you to help me with my main query

Comment: @RicardoRafaelRivas It is possible that AddWithValue is guessing the wrong type when passing the data and causing the problem.

Comment: Como puedo cambiar mi consulta sin utilizar el Addwhitvalue, ayudeme por favor